# Some pictures not showing in application feed

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm in the process of taking a feed from a group & displaying it on a [web page](http://10most.org.uk/).  When logged in to Facebook, the [group time line](https://www.facebook.com/groups/1396648167216137/) shows images that I have posted.  When I put 1396648167216137/feed into the Graph API explorer, I see the "picture" data associated with my posts.  I have used the following PHP code to pull the group feed into the website:

```
// Create our Application instance
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId' => '454419257989387',
  'secret' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', 
));

// Get the Application Access Token
$t = $facebook->getAccessToken();

// Group ID for 10mostinvolved
$gid = "1396648167216137";

// Go fetch the feed
$feed = $facebook->api("$gid/feed?access_token=$t");
```

The pictures from my posts don't show & a dump of the JSON array reveals that the "picture" data isn't being provided in $feed.  The odd thing is that for the 2 other members of the group who have posts with images, the "picture" data is being provided in $feed.

That appears to suggest that it is a setting on my account.  Having looked at the obvious like Settings -> Privacy -> Who can see my stuff? which is set to Public, I am at a loss to explain why my pictures don't show when others do.

Any pointers will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Probably some settings issue or a bug!